# dynamically update listview when a gcm push notification is received without showing it in the notification bar

Tags: android, listview, google-cloud-messaging, push

i am having a group chat feature.every person in the group will receive the push(even the sender of the message).
if the person has opened the group i.e the chatting area is visible, then i want that the push does not show up in the notification bar and it directly update the chat (which i am showing in a listview ).

Initially the chat history i get from web service (when the user open the chat area)

Hope i am able to make you guys clear with what i want to achieve .thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, when you get message in **onMessage()** of **GCMIntentService**, send brodcast. Like,

```
Intent i = new Intent();
                            i.setAction("appendChatScreenMsg");
                            i.putExtra("sender_id", b.getString("sender_id"));
                            i.putExtra("message", b.getString("message"));
                            i.putExtra("time", getCurrentTime());
                            i.putExtra("date", getCurrentDate());
                            this.sendBroadcast(i);
```

Next, Make **BroadcastReceiver** in your Chat activity or Chat Fragment. Like,

```
BroadcastReceiver appendChatScreenMsgReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
        if (b != null) {
            int totalItems = adapter.getCount() - 1;


                ChatModel model = new ChatModel("" + sharedPreferences.getString(VariableBag.USERID, ""), ""+ b.getString("sender_id"), "" + b.getString("message"), b.getString("date"), b.getString("time"));
                arrChat.add(model);


            if (adapter != null) {

                if (lstChat.getLastVisiblePosition() == totalItems) {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    lstChat.setSelection(adapter.getCount());
                } else {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            } else {
                adapter = new ChatAdapter(getActivity());
                lstChat.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                lstChat.setSelection(adapter.getCount());
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Next, Register **BroadcastReceiver** in **onCreate()**. Like

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().registerReceiver(this.appendChatScreenMsgReceiver, new IntentFilter("appendChatScreenMsg"));
}
```

Next, **unregisterReceiver** in **onDestroy()**. Like,

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(appendChatScreenMsgReceiver);
}
```

**Explanation :**

1.) When message is received in GCMIntentService(), first of all, check weather
you are in chat screen or not.

2.) If you are in chat screen, broadcast your message using Intent and Broadcast.

3.) Now, Create your BroadcastReceiver() in chat screen.

4.) Register your BroadcastReceiver() in onCreate() and unregister in onDestroy().

5.) When message is broadcast and you are in chat screen, this broadcast receiver get your bundle.

6.) Now Whatever you want to do.

7.) If you are not in chat screen, then show respected message in notification. Don't broadcast.

**Note:** Be sure in which screen you are currently.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Observer Design Pattern.
set a listener where you display messages and in your service where you get your messages from server check for listener, if listener wasnt null call a update method from listener and update your list else show notification.
example of this patern :
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/DesignPatternObserver/article.html